# Protect a DIV from selection

Tags: html, css

So I have a container div with a clickable slideshow element.  When double clicking the next or previous button, the a few tags after the slideshow element get highlighted.  If I disable the selection of the next div, the double click will select the next div.

As of now I'm using:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

This CSS doesn't work for me because I don't want to disable the selection of a div and all elements within the div, I just want to protect the div child elements from double click selection from another div.  Is there a way to protect a div from selection?

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to select all descendants from your `div` then do the following:

```
div * {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**BUT**, apparently there are issues with speed in this scenario, especially for production. I suggest modifying your HTML and select the `div`'s direct descendants.

```
div h1,
div p,
div span/*, etc. */ {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

If you would like to override the default inheritance of `user-select: none` on the `div`'s children, then for each of those elements add `user-select: text` (including the cross-browser declarations).

Comment: Using * is fine for testing, but you should never use it in production code

Comment: You wanted to grab all descendants of a `div`. If you want to get more specific, use the asterisk selector on a class or ID. I really don't think this is worth a downvote.

Comment: and the reason for this is that CSS parse from `right to left` NOT `left to right`. It means that first it takes ALL elements on the web site and then goes left, to check if they have parent div. this is SLOW. compare it to for example  `* #div` - first it takes ONE element and then checks if its parent is anything - FAST. Without clear statement "don't do this this way in production" i agree it deserves down vote :)

Comment: @Nick - make a quick change to something like this instead div h1, div p { } and write a note that he should add all his descendant elements like that and I'll be happy to change my downvote to an upvote

Comment: * #div and #div are equivalent.

Comment: @NickBeranek The point was to show difference between `* #div` and `#div *`

Comment: Thanks, Tom. @mkk, I understand, but how does that solve the problem? Sure, it is faster, but you're only selecting one element.

Comment: Tom said only that you should never use something like `div *`. My comment was an addition to his comment - I explained why you should avoid it. It was not meant to be solution to the given problem, but for argument why the down vote has been given

Comment: I'm looking to exclude the selection of a div from any outer elements double click but leave the child elements selectable.  Currently I have the slideshow div unselectable.  On the double click of the next arrow and previous arrow within the slideshow div causes the next element outside of the slideshow div in line (div, p, ul etc) to become selected.  I want to isolate the double click selection and only have it effect the current slideshow div since I need users to have the option of selecting the rest of the divs on the page.  I hope this clears everything up.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. You do **not** want the children to be selectable, but rather to be excluded. Therefore, you need to keep the events from bubbling up, which will require some JavaScript. Are you willing to do that?

Comment: OR, for those elements that you specify that need to be selectable, do this: `user-select: text` (add the other cross-browser declarations).

Comment: I'm fine using java if it fixes the issue.  Once I disable an elements selection, the double click of the "next arrow" jumps to the selection of the next element.  I need to figure out a way to turn off this "jump to the next element" selection.

Comment: So you have a `dblclick` event listener on the 'next arrow' and it selects the next element? Can I see a demo of this? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?